# Request AJAX on button

Tags: php, sql, ajax, button, sql-update

I want when I click on a button to send an Ajax 'update' request to my database.
I am well connected to my database which creates me a table with the data of my BDD (only 'SELECT').
mines.php :

```
<?php
include("mines.html");

echo "<html style='background-color: white;'>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm' crossorigin='anonymous'>";
echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
echo "<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
echo "<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>";
echo "</head>";

echo "<table width= '700' border='1' align='center' id='tab_general' style='background-color: #F7741A;'
     <caption align:'center';></caption>";
    echo "<tr align='center'>";

    echo "<TD style='padding:10px; font-size:15px;'>REMORQUE</TD>";
    echo "<TD style='padding:10px; font-size:15px;'>PASSAGE AUX MINES</TD>";
    echo "<TD style='padding:10px; font-size:15px;'>HDUC. 69</TD>";
    echo "<TD style='padding:10px; font-size:15px;'>PASSAGE EFFECTUE LE</TD></TR>";

    $date_jour = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-12 month"));
    $date_limite = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month"));
    $date_jour2 = date("d-m-Y");
    $date_jour3 = date("Y-m-d");
   
    

    $requete_test="SELECT suivi_remorques.suivi_r.remorque, suivi_remorques.suivi_r.mines FROM suivi_remorques.suivi_r WHERE mines BETWEEN '$date_jour' AND '$date_limite' ORDER BY mines ASC";
    $res_test = pg_Exec($database,$requete_test) or die("Erreur Requete $requete_test : ". pg_last_error());

    $requete_lyon ="SELECT remorque as rem1, date as date1, situation FROM suivi_remorques.suivi_rem 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT max(date) AS papa, remorque as rem2 FROM suivi_remorques.suivi_rem
    GROUP BY rem2
    ) AS req ON date = papa and remorque = rem2
    WHERE situation = 'Dispo CMA'";
    $res_lyon = pg_Exec($database,$requete_lyon) or die("Erreur Requete $requete_lyon : ". pg_last_error());

    $requete_lyon_mine ="SELECT remorque as rem1, date as date1, situation FROM suivi_remorques.suivi_rem 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT max(date) AS papa, remorque as rem2 FROM suivi_remorques.suivi_rem
    GROUP BY rem2
    ) AS req ON date = papa and remorque = rem2
    WHERE situation = 'Mines CMA'";
    $res_lyon_mine = pg_Exec($database,$requete_lyon_mine) or die("Erreur Requete $requete_lyon_mine : ". pg_last_error());
    $id = 1;
   for($k=0;$k<pg_NumRows($res_test);$k++) {
      if($k % 2 == 0) {
         echo "<tr align='center' style='background-color: #EDEDED;' id='row_".$row['id']."'>";
      }
      else {
         echo "<tr align='center' id='row_".$row['id']."'>";
      }
      $rem = pg_Result($res_test,$k,"remorque");
      $mines = pg_Result($res_test,$k,"mines");
      $mines_jour = substr($mines, 8, 2);
      $mines_mois = substr($mines, 5, 2);
      $mines_annee= substr($mines, 0, 4);
      echo "<td nowrap style='padding:10px;'>";
      echo $rem;
      echo "</td><td nowrap>";
      echo "$mines_jour/$mines_mois/$mines_annee";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td nowrap style='padding:10px;'>";
      $lyon_match = '';
      for ($j = 0; $j < pg_NumRows($res_lyon); $j++) {
         if($rem == pg_Result($res_lyon, $j, "rem1")) {
            //$lyon_match = pg_Result($res_lyon, $j, "remorque");
            echo "Dispo CMA";
         }
      }
      for ($m = 0; $m < pg_NumRows($res_lyon_mine); $m++) {
         if($rem == pg_Result($res_lyon_mine, $m, "rem1")) {
            //$lyon_match = pg_Result($res_lyon, $j, "remorque");
            echo "Mines CMA";
         }
      }
      echo $lyon_match;
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td class='px-4 py-2'>";
      
      echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal'>";
      echo "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-pencil-square' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>";
      echo "<path d='M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z'/>";
      echo "<path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z'/>";
      echo "</svg>";
      echo "</button>";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $id++;

      echo "<!-- Modal -->";
      echo "<div class='modal fade' id='editModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='editModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>";
      echo "  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>";
      echo "    <div class='modal-content'>";
      echo "      <div class='modal-header'>";
      echo "        <h5 class='modal-title' id='editModalLabel'>Modification</h5>";
      echo "        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>";
      echo "          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>";
      echo "        </button>";
      echo "      </div>";
      echo "      <div class='modal-body text-center'>";
      echo "        <p>La remorque est passee le :</p>";
      echo "        $date_jour2";
      echo "        <br><br>";
      echo "        <button type='button' name='update' class='btn btn-primary' id='validate'>Valider</button>";
      echo "      </div>";
      echo "      <div class='modal-footer'>";
      echo "        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Fermer</button>";
      echo "      </div>";
      echo "    </div>";
      echo "  </div>";
      echo "</div>";
   }
echo "</table>";
echo "</html>";
$update = $_POST['query'];
$result = pg_query($conn, $update);

if (pg_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo "Update OK";
} else {
  echo "Erreur lors de l'exécution de la requête : " . pg_last_error($conn);
}

pg_close($conn);
?>
```

I generate the 'trailer' column in this way which works well:
I assign an id for each line generated

```
for($k=0;$k<pg_NumRows($res_test);$k++) {
      if($k % 2 == 0) {
         echo "<tr align='center' style='background-color: #EDEDED;' id='row_".$row['id']."'>";
      }
      else {
         echo "<tr align='center' id='row_".$row['id']."'>";
      }
      $rem = pg_Result($res_test,$k,"remorque");
      $mines = pg_Result($res_test,$k,"mines");
      $mines_jour = substr($mines, 8, 2);
      $mines_mois = substr($mines, 5, 2);
      $mines_annee= substr($mines, 0, 4);
      echo "<td nowrap style='padding:10px;'>";
      echo $rem;
      echo "</td><td nowrap>";
```

File mines.html :

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#validate').click(function() {
      var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
      var rem = $('#' + row_id + ' td:first').text();
      var update = "UPDATE suivi_remorques.suivi_rem SET situation = 'Mine CMA' WHERE remorque = '" + rem + "'";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mines.php',
        data: {query: update},
        success: function(data) {
           alert( "Update OK");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the 'Update OK' alert displayed but no database update.

I tried with a select instead of an 'update' for the query and display it in the alert, it doesn't work either.
The queries are correct

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of echoing a bunch of HTML through PHP, you can make the code _way_ more readable, less prone to typos and easier to debug by closing the PHP block: `?>`, adding the HTML to output, and start the PHP block again: `<?php` when you need it. Then IDE's will be able to syntax highlight both the HTML and PHP.

Comment: **Warning!** Your code is giving any user the ability to execute _what ever query they want_. Remember that the users have full access to your JS (and can change it to what ever they like). _Never_ trust user input.